# Concatenate string variables with a dot to separate them (.)

Tags: c#, .net, string, concatenation

I have three variables,

```
string val1 = "Name";
string val2 = "Gender";
string val3 = "Age";
```

What is the most efficient way of having a another variable which will have the value stored as

```
val4 = Name.Gender.Age ;
```

Note:- I do understand you can simply do this with something like

```
string val4 = val1 +"."+ val2+"." + val3;
```

but is there any built in method to do so ?

Comment: Why you are particular with efficiency of string concatenation? What is the big picture behind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the built-in `Join` method on the `string` class:

```
var val4 = string.Join(".", val1, val2, val3);
```